# Extracting rows results in empty object

Tags: r, dataset, row, record

I'm working with occurrence records and want to remove records that are missing coordinates, with the line:

```
records0 <- records[records$decimalLatitude == 0 | records$decimalLongitude == 0,]
```

(`decimalLatitude` and `decimalLongitude` are two of my columns)

But when I look at `records0`, it shows the right number of rows for which the coordinates are missing, but all of the other columns are empty as well (shows `NA` when they should still contain the rest of my data).
Why could that be? (The object `records` containing my dataset looks as it should.)

> records <- fread("Occurrences-Example.csv")

> dput(records[1:4, ])
> structure(list(rightsHolder = c("", "", "Naturalis Biodiversity Center",
> "Naturalis Biodiversity Center"), type = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), decimalLatitude = c(-4.565474,
> NA, NA, -0.832667), decimalLongitude = c(12.480469, NA, NA, 13.9735
> ), scientificName = c("Gigasiphon gossweileri (Baker f.) Torre & Hillc.",
> "Gigasiphon gossweileri (Baker f.) Torre & Hillc.", "Bauhinia humblotiana Baill.",
> "Gigasiphon gossweileri (Baker f.) Torre & Hillc.")), row.names = c(NA,
> -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f8dfc812ee0>)

> records0 <- records[records$decimalLatitude == 0 | records$decimalLongitude == 0,]
> records0
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: rightsHolder,type,decimalLatitude,decimalLongitude,scientificName

Comment: Can you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data?

Comment: If a record is missing coordinates, are the longitude and latitude zero (0) or `NA`? Your code is checking if equal to zero, but your example data has `NA` I assume for missing elements? Perhaps you might want: `records0 <- records[is.na(records$decimalLatitude) | is.na(records$decimalLongitude),]`? That would use `is.na` to check for `NA` in your data.

Comment: If a record is missing coordinates, they are "NA" in this case, but if i replace "0" with "NA" in records0 <- records[records$decimalLatitude == 0 | records$decimalLongitude == 0,], it seems to still read the same rows as having missing coordinates (it does the same thing). records0 <- records[is.na(records$decimalLatitude) | is.na(records$decimalLongitude),] also gives the same result (records is empty).

Comment: Hmmm...I used your example data with the line of code using `is.na` and got two rows of data back...

Comment: Thanks. It works on the example but not on my full dataset

Comment: So it works for `records[1:4,]` but not `records`? Are there other differences to consider?

Comment: Actually, it's working for records, but when I try to remove the missing occurrences from records, records becomes empty.                                                                        
 > recordsNA <- records[is.na(records$decimalLatitude) | is.na(records$decimalLongitude),]
> records <- records[!records$ID %in% recordsNA$ID,] 
> records
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 241 cols: gbifID,abstract,accessRights,accrualMethod,accrualPeriodicity,accrualPolicy...

Comment: This isn't reproducible for me as the example data does not have an `ID` column. Also, your statement `records <- records[...]` overwrites `records`, so be aware that may also make debugging more confusing. If you are willing, please edit your question with a reproducible example having `ID`.